# Where can I find a large number of fish?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

Nearly every crafting/carry capacity upgrade needs fish bones/skin for the final, end-game items. I want to stop carrying animal bits as soon as possible, since my inventory is full of stuff I may or may not need from every animal in the game.

So, where can I go fishing? Are there areas on the map where Trout spawn in greater numbers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This guide](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/find-fish-horizon-zero-dawn/) lists a specific lake as a good place to find fish. The lake appears to be on the Carja side of the map, as southern as you can go directly west of the Daytower.

> [image: lake]
>
> You want to reach the lake featured in the screenshot above. It’s not a very dangerous area at lower levels but there are some Snapmaw nearby so if you’re under level 10, be cautious. In the lake you will find several spawns of fish, most of which respawn rather quickly if you just swim to the other side.

Comment: That did it. You were right too about swimming from one side to the other; anywhere between 2 and 6 fish would respawn on my way back.

Comment: There's also a settlement northwest of Meridian, on the southern shore of Lake Powell, where you can walk out on a pier and spot ~5 fish, shoot them, then walk to another pier and shoot some more.